# How to merge commits previously rejected/reverted?

Tags: git

I have a branch `A` that was previously merged into `dev` and later reverted due to some issues.

After a long time, I want to merge again that branch `A` on `dev`, but it's not updating the `dev` branch now. Instead it shows that `Already updated`.

How do I merge the commits from `A` to `dev`?

I have also tried to pull `dev` branch locally and merge them on `A`. But it overwrites the changes on `A`.

I know there are some hacky ways like copy pasting the changes. But there are a lot of changes and I want to know the proper way to do this.

Comment: See [Reverting a git merge while allowing for the same merge later](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57904970/reverting-a-git-merge-while-allowing-for-the-same-merge-later/57905240#57905240).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to do a "git revert" of the *revert* commit you performed on the branch `A` and then merge to `dev` branch

Answer (score 0):

You need to "revert the revert".

In other words, find the commit that reverted the original merge and revert that one.

However, in general you should avoid reverting a merge. See [How to revert a faulty merge](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/howto/revert-a-faulty-merge.txt) from the official docs for more details.