# Re-merging a reverted merge that failed due to bad conflict resolution

Tags: git, git-merge, git-revert

First, I have studied [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1078209/1270789) but it doesn't quite match my situation. We currently have this:

```
---o---o---C---M---W  <-- develop
              /
      ---A---B        <-- new_feature
```

When I tried to merge B with C (`git checkout develop && git merge new_feature`), there was a bunch of conflicts that I fixed, and pushed M as the result. The person who wrote C was testing, and found that my merge M had lost some of his changes, so he did a `git revert M` to get W, which code-wise is identical to C. Now, I have been asked to try again, but as mentioned in the linked answer, the history includes a flag to say that `new_feature` has been merged so trying to repeat `git merge B` gives me the message:

```
Already up-to-date.
```

Doing a `reset` is going to confuse all our downstream CI processes, so I cannot do that. There's four commits in the `new_feature` branch, so is a `cherry-pick` my best option, but I'm not sure if cherry-picking multiple commits is equivalent to merging a branch. Or is `git revert --no-commit W` then manually checking where the changes in C went the easiest option?

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57905240/6868543).

Comment: That's interesting, and might even be a dup of this question. I ended up doing the `git revert --no-commit W`, though, and fortunately it was only one file that had messed up its merge.