# Subsequent merge after `merge --squash` cause conflicts

Tags: git

Normal merge:

```
$ git merge feature01
$ git merge feature02
```

Everything works fine.

squash merge:

```
$ git merge --squash feature01 # OK
$ git merge --squash feature02
Auto-merging src/aaa.js
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in src/XXX.js
....
```

Why is that? How to make `merge --squash` work(subsequent merge works find)?

Comment: Is there common history of festure01 and feature02 that is not part of the branch you are working on?

Comment: I'm not sure, I just merge the branches other developers created

Answer (score 1):

The situation that you describe requires that the history looks something like this:

```
--X--Y             <-- your master
   \
    A--B--C--D     <-- feature01
     \
      R--S--T      <-- feature02
```

<sub>(Whether your `master` has a commit `Y` or is still at `X` is irrelevant for the following.)</sub>

> Why is that?

Notice that the two features have commits in  common, `A`  in this example. When you do regular merges, Git knows about this fact and can deal with it without generating conflicts. In particular, in the second merge it will **not** pull in the changes made in `A` again.

But when you do a squash merge of `feature01`, you are generating this history:

```
--X--Y--F1         <-- your master
   \
    A--R--S--T     <-- feature02
```

I truncated `feature01` from the picture because it does not play a role anymore.

When you do a merge of `feature02` now (squash or regular does not matter), Git attempts to apply commit `A` again, because it does not have enough information to know that it has already merged it. The conflicts arise when one of the commits `B`, `C`, `D` have made changes in the vicinity of the changes that `A` did.

> How to make `merge --squash` work (subsequent merge works fine)?

You cannot. Do not use `merge --squash`.

Of course, you can jump through some hoops by [grafting history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57904970/reverting-a-git-merge-while-allowing-for-the-same-merge-later/57905240#57905240) to pretend that `A` was actually merged into `F1`; but it is just a work-around, a band-aid for emergency cases, but that is too tedious for a regular workflow. And if you do that, why didn't you use a regular merge in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

Well.... my hunch is that there is common history of feature01 and feature02 that is outside of the branch you are working on.... when you do normal merges, git can see that and it is part of the merge calculation... but if you merge with squash, that common history is then gone from gits sight and it might cause conflicts.... for example, on the second branch that you merge you *modify* a change that was introduced on the first merged  branch.... if you tried merging it, to git there's no historical context to figure out that you started from the change on the first branch.... so you would get a conflict.

Answer (score 0):

(as @eftshift0 mentioned in his comment : )

If, before merge, the history of your two branches look like this :

```
# featureA and featureB have some common history :
--*--*--x--a <- master
         \
          *--*--y--b <- featureA
                 \
                  *--*--*--c <- featureB
```

- When running `git merge featureA`, git uses the existing commits :

  ```
  --*--*--x--a---------b' <- master
           \          /
            *--*--y--b <- featureA
                   \
                    *--*--*--c <- featureB
  ```

  and it has enough information to know that it should use `y` as a merge base for `featureB`,
- When running `git merge --squash featureB` on the other hand :

  ```
  --*--*--x--a--b' <- master
           \
            *--*--y--b <- featureA
                   \
                    *--*--*--c <- featureB
  ```

  It creates a new commit, which is not related to branch `featureB` anymore, and it will try to re-apply the changes `x..y` when merging `featureB`.

---

You can look at the history of your branches  :

- from the command line : `git log --graph featureA featureB master`
- or using a gui client : `git gui`, `git-kraken`, `git-extensions`, ...