# How can I merge the same code that was roll-backed with git revert?

Tags: git, github

The scenario is as below:

Assume that the state of `master` and `develop` branches are `A`, `feature/issue-1` branch is `B`.
`feature/issue-1` branch is created from `master` branch.

1. Merge the code of branch `feature/issue-1` into `master` branch.
   Now `master` branch has `B` code.
2. Some errors found.
   Revert the merged commits at `master` branch, with `git revert MERGE_COMMIT -m 1` command.
   Now `master` branch has `A` code.
3. Merge the code of branch `feature/issue-1` into `develop` branch.
   Now, `develop` branch has `B` code.
4. Create `feature/issue-2` branch from `develop` branch.
   Now `feature/issue-2` branch has `B` code.
5. Add some codes in `feature/issue-2` branch.
   Now `feature/issue-2` branch has `B` + `C` code.
6. Merge the code of branch `feature/issue-2` into `develop` branch.
   Now `develop` branch has `B` + `C` code.
7. Trying to merge the code of branch `develop` into `master` branch.

I'm in the number 7 situation.

I opened a pull request to merge develop branch into master branch.

But when I check `file changed` in the opened pull requests, changes about `B` are not shown, and only `C` is shown.

Is this because I reverted `B` code before?

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Just a note : at step 2 you should have opted for either resetting to rewind master history back (if possible in your work context) or reverting actual commits (and optionnally squashing them all in one big revert) rather than the merge commit. If you had done the latter, now it would be simple : just revert the revert.

Comment: Yes, the reversal of `B` on the `master` branch is the reason for your state. In this case, I think the most reasonable way forward is to revert the revert. You could also think whether [this workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57904970/reverting-a-git-merge-while-allowing-for-the-same-merge-later/57905240#57905240) could work for you.