# Best practices to un-merge a branch such that it can be re-merged?

Tags: git, git-merge

Let's say I merge a feature branch `feature/123` into `master`, then a problem occurs and we have to remove it.  So far I know about two ways to do this:

1. `git revert --mainline 1 <commitid> && git push`
   (where `<commitid>` is the merge commit)
2. `git checkout master && git reset --hard <commitid> && git push --force`
   (where `<commitid>` is from before the merge commit)

#1 has an issue where if `feature/123` is fixed and needs to be re-merged into `master`, only a portion of the work will be merged in.  (Specifically, the work that was done *since* it was merged into master the first time.)

#2 has that whole "repository surgery" issue where if anyone else pulled master in the intervening time, have fun.

Are there other solutions to un-doing a merge that have neither of the above issues?  #1 seems to be the least bad because developers can recreate their branches and replay their work into them but I don't want that either.

Comment: Go ahead with `git revert`. Then when you want to merge the branch again, use `git replace --graft` like I explain in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57904970/reverting-a-git-merge-while-allowing-for-the-same-merge-later/57905240#57905240).

Comment: Hi Darren! If any of the answers below answered your question, please go ahead and mark it as answered. Here's more on asking and answering questions: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

Option 1 is definitely the more hygienic option, and your concern is a very valid and well documented one =D. Here's an idea from [this article](https://www.datree.io/resources/git-undo-merge) from datree.io:

> If the faulty side branch was fixed by adding corrections on top, then doing a revert of the previous revert would be the right thing to do.

From the same article, here is a [previous thread](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/howto/revert-a-faulty-merge.txt) from Git's official docs answering the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

[The answer by Ali Dowair](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64917201/11932806) links to the right discussions. But to best understand how to fix it I'd like to explain what is going wrong here first:

After your second merge your history looks something like this:

```
*   master
|\
| * (F2) fixing commit on feature branch
* |
* | (R) revert of merge commit (M)
* |
* | (M) merge of feature into master
|\|
| * (F) faulty commit on feature branch
|/
*   (B) common base commit
|
```

So, when you do a `git merge feature` on the `master` branch `git` will look for the common *base commit* in those two branches and merge all changes from `feature` committed since that *base commit*.

By the second time you `git merge`d this base commit was `F` with the faulty changes, i.e. `F` was already included in `master` and `feature` and thus `git` determined only `F2` needed to be merged.

As the [linked discussions](https://www.datree.io/resources/git-undo-merge) in [the answer by Ali Dowair](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64917201/11932806) say

> So if you think of "revert" as "undo", then you're going to always miss this part of reverts. Yes, it undoes the data, but no, it doesn't undo history.

So since `F` is already included in `master` - as far as `git` is able to detect this - it won't be merged again leaving you with two options (ignoring rewriting/force-pushing the history here):

1. Revert the revert: `git revert R` right before you `git merge feature` again. This will re-apply the previously merged and then undone changes - i.e. `F` in this example - and then apply/merge the new changes from the feature branch:

```
*   master
|\
| * (F2) fixing commit on feature branch
* | (R') revert of revert commit (R)
* |
* | (R) revert of merge commit (M)
* |
* | (M) merge of feature into master
|\|
| * (F) faulty commit on feature branch
|/
*   (B) common base commit
|
```

2. Rebase `feature` onto the new `master` after the revert:

```sh
git checkout feature
git rebase B --onto master
# rebases all commits done since (B) onto the new master

git checkout master
git merge feature
```

Resulting in:

```
*   master
|\
| * (F2') fixing commit on feature branch
* |
| * (F') faulty commit on feature branch
|/
*
|
*   (R) revert of merge commit (M)
|
| * (F2) fixing commit on feature branch
| |
* | (M) merge of feature into master
|\|
| * (F) faulty commit on feature branch
|/
*   (B) common base commit
|
```

Here `git merge` will pull in the changes from `F'` and `F2'` which are the rebased versions of `F` and `F2`. Using `--onto` here is necessary to stick to the original *base commit* `B` here because just `git rebase master` would omit `F` for the same reasons `git merge` would do.

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following:

Step 1: if it has already been merged into master, then I would create the branch from the merged commit point:

```
git checkout master   // checkout the master branch
git log               // to find the commit point where feature/123 was merged in
git checkout <commit-hash>   // checkout the commit point 
                             // (you will get a warning about a detached head)
git checkout -b feature123 // create a new branch from this commit (you'll be remerging this later)
git push origin feature123 // push this branch to the server
```

Step 2: surgically remove the commit point from master history by doing an interactive rebase:

```
git checkout master // checkout the master branch
git pull origin master  // get latest of master
git log   // to find a commit point that is past the commit point from. i.e. <any-commit-point>
git rebase -i <any-commit-point> // start an interactive rebase

(opens up editor)

pick dbf4522c
drop 035d52e0  // drop the target commit from Step 1
pick 02441dee

(complete the rebase)

git push origin master --force // force push to server (be careful!)
```

You may have to resolve merge conflicts as part of this rebase.

Step 3: Merge `feature123` branch back into master

```
git checkout feature123
git merge master
git add *
git commit
git push origin master
```

Finally, since you've re-written history on the master branch, make sure to let everyone know to re-clone the repository.