# Resolving merge conflicts after reverting a merge commit

Tags: git, git-merge, git-revert, git-merge-conflict

I have merged a feature branch into develop. After that I have found a bug in the feature branch code so I have reverted the merge (branch develop) :

```
git revert -m 1 <merge-commit-hash> 
git push origin develop
```

Next I have fixed the bug on the feature branch. In the meantime some other branches have been merged into develop. I have created a pull request (feature branch -> develop) with the fix but it can't be merged into develop due to conflicts. I would like to have a pull request without conflicts. When I try to merge develop into feature branch to resolve conflicts the code from the feature branch is reverted (probably due to earlier revert of merge). How to fix that ?

Comment: Did you fix the bug with a new commit on top of the feature branch? Or did you make a completely new feature branch? Or did you rewrite just some commits of the feature branch?

Comment: I have just created a new commit on top of the existing feature branch.

Comment: I haven't removed a feature branch after merge so I have checkouted to the feature branch and pushed a next commit with the fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have this history (time flows left to right):

```
        ...   ...
            \     \
----------M--o--R--o    <-- develop
         /
--1--2--3--F            <-- feature
```

You have created commits `1`, `2`, `3` on your feature branch and merged it into develop at commit `M`. Then you discovered that there is a bug and reverted it at commit `R` (before or after other branches have been merged; it does not matter).

Now you have fixed the problem with commit `F` and you want to merge the feature again. This brings a lot of trouble (merge conflicts), because `F` depends on the changes you made on the feature branch, but `develop` no longer has them (you have reverted them in `R`).

One way out is that your revert the revert and then merge the updated feature branch:

```
git checkout develop
git revert R
git merge feature
```

That should not produce the merge conflicts, but result in this history:

```
        ...   ...
            \     \
----------M--o--R--o--R'--N    <-- develop
         /               /
--1--2--3--F------------'      <-- feature
```

`R'` is the reversal of the revert `R`.

Another method is to make Git think that the earlier merge has never happend using `git replace --graft` as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57905240/6868543).

Yet another method is to create a completely new feature branch.  Assuming `1` is the first commit that was merged in `M`, it could go like this:

```
git checkout feature
git rebase --force-rebase 1^
git checkout develop
git merge feature
```

`git rebase --force-rebase 1^` ensures that commits `1`, `2`, `3`, `F` are copied and creates a new branch that forks off at the same point that the original branch forked off. You get this history:

```
        ...   ...
            \     \
----------M--o--R--o--N    <-- develop
         /           /
--1--2--3--F        /      <-- abandoned feature branch
--1'--2'--3'--F'---'       <-- feature
```

Of course, you can choose a new fork point for the feature branch. `R` would be the natural choice.

Comment: Usually the pull request is waiting for approval for some time. I would like to have a pull request without conflicts (I use Bitbucket) but after reverting `R` a branch develop exists some time with a bug which is not a good practice.

Comment: You have painted yourself into a corner by reverting the commit. I've added another idea to the answer that let's you get away without the reversal of the revert. But it's an advanced technique.

Comment: What about using rebase ? Maybe it could help.

Comment: Rebasing can help if you do it correctly.

Comment: Could you please propose a solution which utilizes rebasing? The answer will be more complete.

Comment: I've added a suggestion using `git rebase`.