# Redo a git merge and see the file changes previously reverted

Tags: git

I've merged a project from my `abc` branch to my `xyz` branch. I'm used to add the flags `no-commit --no-ff` in order to view all changes and approve them before commiting and pushing.
So I received like 6 changed files from this merge, I reverted 3 of them and used the remaining 3 as my merge commit.

Now I want to repeat the operation, retrieving once again these 3 files from `abc` branch. But whenever I run `git merge abc --no-commit --no-ff`, I don't get the 3 chnged files anymore.

How can I ignore this past merge and see everything that is different between my 2 branches?

Comment: You told Git that the changes from the merged commits in these 3 files should be ignored; now they are ignored. You can try to re-apply the patches from the merged commits into a new branch, then merge the new branch (containing the same, but new, changes)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reverting a git merge while allowing for the same merge later)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57904970/reverting-a-git-merge-while-allowing-for-the-same-merge-later)

Comment: So, you reverted them, but you didn't mean to revert them?

Comment: Thanks for showing the possibilities, guys! Unfortunatelly due to the nature of this project  I just cloned the source branch in a different place, copied the files and pasted it in my dir. Very manual merging operation, hehe